# Live streaming 360 video

Tags: live-streaming, http-live-streaming, 360-virtual-reality

I need to develop functionality for 360 live streaming. I have 'Insta 360 air' web camera for tests (max resolution for video 2560x1280).
I try to use Wowza Streaming Cloud and OBS or Wirecast broadcaster for the live streaming from PC.
Video has a lot of lags, I think that is because broadcaster uses CPU 90%, RAM 90% and GPU 80-90%.

Maybe who knows alternatives ways for live streaming 360 video.
Maybe WEBRTC to RTMP?

Comment: Your choice of protocol isn't going to improve the stitching.  I'm guessing this camera requires stitching on your PC?  Or does it stitch on device?

Comment: This may help - you are on the right track, in that you have selected a camera which actually supports 360 live streaming, which not all do: http://360rumors.com/2017/08/insta360-pro-tutorial-connect-internet-live-stream.html